# geomap with SQl server database

Tags: asp.net

I am working on google chart and developing a application for the geomap ,I am fetching the data form the SQl table .Everything I am doing correct even system is not showing any error while debugging but Map is not displaying :My code is as under :
.aspx page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="testchart.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['geomap'] });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);
      $(function () {
            //For Pie chart
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetgeomapData',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                function (response) {
                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap(response.d));
                },

                error: function () {
                    alert("Error loading data!");
                }
            });
        });
          function drawMap(dataValues) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'City');
                data.addColumn('number', 'FIC');

                for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

                    data.addRow([dataValues[i].EmployeeCity,dataValues[i].FIC]);
                    }
                 var options = {};
                options['region'] = 'IN';
                options['colors'] = [0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]; //orange colors

                var geomap = new google.visualization.geomap(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                geomap.draw(data, options);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map_canvas'></div>
</body>

</html>

.aspx.cs 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace testchart
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        // Pie chart
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<employeeDetails> GetgeomapData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Data-SERVER;Initial Catalog=GISDATABASE;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select *from TestTable", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
            List<employeeDetails> dataList = new List<employeeDetails>();
            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
            {
                employeeDetails details = new employeeDetails();
                details.EmployeeCity = dtrow[0].ToString();
                details.FIC = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow[1]);
                dataList.Add(details);
            }
            return dataList;
        }
        public class employeeDetails
        {

            public string EmployeeCity { get; set; }


            public object Value { get; set; }



            public string MIROUND { get; set; }

            public int FIC { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me out for this .Quick help is really appreciable .

Comment: Can any one help out please ?